# How to get document element when I use external script in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React to build my project. I made a chat button by using external script. And I'd like to disappear that button in some specific pages. I can't use a ref to access that button's element So I used document.getElementById.
But my problem is my code sometimes returns error. (I think when my code runs, chat button didn't run by external script.) How can I solve this problem?

```
    useEffect(() => {
//access chat button element by using document.getElementById
        const chatBtn = document.getElementById('ch-plugin-launcher');

//if it doesn't exist in current page, it returns.
        if (!chatBtn) {
            return;
        }

//if a button exists, it will be hide.
        chatBtn.classList.add('hide');

        return () => {
            chatBtn.classList.remove('hide');
        };
    }, []);
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Other than polling for the element, what can you do when this component mounts and checks, and the target element isn't in the DOM? What is this external script? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error in return of `useEffect`. You return a function, which can be called at any time whenever the chat button does not exist. Add check for existing on the chat button in the `useEffect` return function. Other code looks well.

```
useEffect(() => {
 // Your code
 
 return () => {
    document.getElementById('ch-plugin-launcher')?.classList?.remove('hide');
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @0x6368656174 answwer is correct.
Just for more clarification why:

> When exactly does React clean up an effect? React performs the cleanup
> when the component unmounts. However, as we learned earlier, effects
> run for every render and not just once. This is why React also cleans
> up effects from the previous render before running the effects next
> time. We’ll discuss why this helps avoid bugs and how to opt out of
> this behavior in case it creates performance issues later below.

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1